# Do While loop skipping user input in C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, do-while

Having some difficulty figuring out the right syntax I should be using when trying to get the Do/While loop to work. I would like to write a calculator in C++ that allows the user to enter a string and then it does its thing and prints the result, asks the user if they want to go again or not.

I have a simple main function so far just to get the Do/While loop right, but when I enter y or Y, the program just asks if I want to continue again, it doesnt give me the opporunity to run the "calculator" part again. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> //cout, cin
#include <string> //string
#include <algorithm> //remove_if(), end(), begin(), erase()
#include <stack> //stack<type>
#include <ctype.h> //isdigit()
#include <vector> //vectors
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string userInput = ""; //declaring and initialising a string called user input
    char ans;

    do {

        cout << "Welcome to the calculator, please enter your calculation and then press enter when you are done." << endl;
        cin >> userInput;

        userInput.erase(remove_if(userInput.begin(), userInput.end(), isspace), userInput.end()); //removes and then erases any spaces in the string
        userInput.erase(remove_if(userInput.begin(), userInput.end(), isalpha), userInput.end()); // removes and then erases any alphabetic charecters
                                                                                                  //this will leave only numbers and operators
        cout << userInput << endl;
        cout << "Would you like to continue?" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter 'y' or 'n'" << endl;
        cin >> ans;

    } while ((ans == 'y')||(ans == 'Y'));

    return 0;
}
```

[image: This is what I get in the Termninal]

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Your loop seems to work. However the code breaks on some input (e.g. containing `ä`).

Comment: It might depend on how you type the input. `cin >> userInput;` only reads one word and stops at the first whitespace, leaving the rest in the input buffer.

Comment: @wkl I will get an image and add it to my post so you can see what I am getting.

Comment: @BoPersson I see, I was originally using getline but I thought that was the issue as to why it was skipping through. I would prefer top use getline.

Comment: You should insert `userInput=""` after `cin >> ans;`

Comment: @Ben - `getline` has a different problem when mixed with `>>` :-(  See [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `cin >> userInput;` stops on the first whitespace, and my money is on a typical input string of yours containing plenty of them.

Change to

`std::getline(std::cin, userInput);`

This will gobble up a whole line of input, and deal with the newline character automatically for you.

For an easy life, do something similar with `ans`. Redefine it as a `std::string`. `std::string` even has `==` overloaded for a `char` type!

(Personally I'd also refrain from commenting standard `#include` files. Any C++ programmer should know what they "bring in", and this can lead to disinformation as your program expands.)

Comment: So even with `getline` being used, the execution is exactly the same, it just skips right past the opportunity for me to enter another string.

Comment: Did you change the type of `ans`? I would if I were you. I hate reading in a single `char`.

Comment: I also do not understand why I would need to change the type of `ans` I have defined it as a `char` as the user will only be entering one character? @Bathsheba

Comment: Humour me and try it.

Comment: @Bethsheba I changed it, but no difference

Comment: @BenRichi_ you're missing a scope resolution operator on `isspace` and `isalpha` . Try putting `::isspace` and `::isalpha` instead. It works on my computer.

Comment: @mutantkeyboard I made the change you recommended but the issue is still the same, I do not get why this works on some computers but not mine...

Comment: @BenRichi_ here is the code -> https://pastebin.com/Ui5UTLDC ... please give it a try. Also make sure to clean the project, and rebuild again. And please try to avoid including `stdafx.h`

Comment: @BenRichi_ what's inside your "stdafx.h" ?

Comment: @mutantkeyboard If I do not include stdafx.h then Visual Studio hates everything and just throws up errors for everything

Comment: @BenRichi_ just create a new project, and when it asks you turn off the option for precompiled headers. More info -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222922/when-do-i-want-to-turn-off-precompiled-header-in-visual-studio

Comment: I think in this link you can find useful suggestions for what you want to solve: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046/

Answer (score 0):

So I have finally overcome my issue with help from @Bathsheba and @mutantkeyboard

I was using `getline` but only for the first instance of user input, like @Bathsheba suggests. This was not working for me as I then left the input for the `ans` as `cin`. Changing both of these to `getline` not just one of them and using a blank project without a pre-compiled header has solved the issue for me. The projects now loops correctly as expected.

Thank you for your help everyone!